# Hadoop metrics via REST API: allocatedMB, allocatedVcores and runningContainers is always -1

Tags: java, rest, hadoop

we try to report our monthly hadoop application metrics for each user and use the REST API using the following REST API path:

http://[host:port]/ws/v1/cluster/app

The returned data looks good except allocatedMB, allocatedVcores and runningContainers which is always -1.

Can anybody explain why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no running jobs on your cluster when you call the RM cluster apps API you are looking historical data.  Based on the Hadoop code (QueueStatisticsPBImpl.java under hadoop-yarn-project/), -1 is used as a default value when the RM doesn't know the value of that item.

```
@Override
public long getAllocatedVCores() {
  QueueStatisticsProtoOrBuilder p = viaProto ? proto : builder;
  return (p.hasAllocatedVCores()) ? p.getAllocatedVCores() : -1;
}
```

Since the other fields are values that would stored in the Job History Server (other than `allocatedMB`, `allocatedVCores`, and `runningContainers`), they contain actual values.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer regarding Hadoop 3.x. I could not find the correct assignment for allocatedVCores in Hadoop 2.x but a comment in ApplicationResourceUsageReport says that -1 is set if the application data is invalid or inaccessible. For me the problem was, that the application data was no longer stored on our history server so I could not access it anymore.